# Is it possible to make Razor Pages refresh when the cshtml is saved without restarting?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I'm having issue developing an mvc project with Razor Pages. I have the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation package installed (v7.0.1) to enable live view compilation. However, this isn't working for Razor Pages. I checked, and can update regular MVC views, however, changing any updates inside Razor Page cshtml files isn't propagated until I restart the debugger.

Is it possible for Pages to be refreshed this way, and if so, what settings could I be missing?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-compilation?view=aspnetcore-8.0&tabs=visual-studio)

> Runtime compilation:
>
> Isn't supported for Razor components of Blazor apps.
>
> Doesn't support global using directives.
>
> Doesn't support implicit using directives.
>
> Disables .NET Hot Reload.
>
> Is recommended for development, not for production.

And for your requirement

> Is it possible to make Razor Pages refresh when the cshtml is saved
> without restarting?

You could try with [hot reload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/hot-reload?view=aspnetcore-8.0),it would be enabled by default:

[image]